# Python not receiving json HTTP response correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to use the GENIUS API with python, but i don't get a full response.

Code:

```
base_url = "http://api.genius.com"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ExYL8I-s_5jmbMPobq9WtNpywmmATJr5owM1X3DPIiGI_uYJJRrsKv6Y26KrxVCy'}
/* temporary key */
song_title = "Radioactive"
search_url = base_url + "/search"    
data = {'q': song_title}
response = requests.get(search_url, data=data, headers=headers)
json_r = response.json()
```

The response that I'm getting is:

```
{'meta': {'status': 200}, 'response': {'hits': []}}
```

The json parser is not parsing what's in the [ ] ...(square brackets). I then tried it in javscript using jquery and ajax and it worked perferctly, and received all the json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change http to https:

```
base_url = "https://api.genius.com"
```